# bash show output only during runtime

Tags: bash

I am trying to write a script that displays its output to the terminal only while it's running, much like the 'less' or 'ssh' commands.

When I launch said script, it would take over the whole terminal, print what it needs to print, and then when I exit the script, I would return to my terminal where the only record that my script has run will be the line that shows the command itself. When I scroll up, I don't want to see what my script output.

```
[snoopdougg@machine /home/snoopdougg/logs]$ ls
alog.log      blog.log      clog.log      myScript.sh
[snoopdougg@machine /home/snoopdougg/logs]$ whoami
snoopdougg
[snoopdougg@machine /home/snoopdougg/logs]$ ./myScript.sh
[snoopdougg@machine /home/snoopdougg/logs]$
```

(Like nothing ever happened... but myScript.sh would have print things to the terminal while it was running).

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're talking about the alternate screen, which you can access with a pair of terminal attributes, `smcup` and `rmcup`. Put this in a script and run it for a small demo:

```
tput smcup
echo hello
sleep 5
tput rmcup
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/):

```
screen ./myScript.sh
```